# Get the Old input of googleMap in update form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, google-maps-api-3

Am building a form that the user will be able to provide his information and also provide where he want the bus to pick him up  , so am using google Map Api , so that he can provide coordinates , this is done .
but now in the update form i cant get the Coordinates values from User Object
 so that i can update them , 
this is the result of User::first() "dummy data btw"

```
{"id":1,"name":"Hady2","email":"Hady2@mtc.com","created_at":"2017-08-24 00:25:19","updated_at":"2017-08-24 00:25:19","MobileNo":"111111","Age":12,"Gender":2,"OrganizationId":1,"Location":"30.03914,31.081119","CheckInLocation":"30.4414,31.00019","CheckOutLocation":"30.02914,31.111119","BusId":1}
```

u will see up the coordinates variables , i want to use them so that they appear in their fields in the update form ,
 and then i able to update them,
update form code :-
this is start form code :-

```
{!! Form::model($user,['route'=>['users.update',$user->id], 'method'=> 'PUT']) !!}
```

this a user name tag , to show u how i get the old value to the user name input

```
{!!Form::text('name','',array('required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'class'=>'form-control'))!!}-->
                {!! Form::text('name',$user->name, [
        'class'                         => 'form-control',
        'placeholder'                   => 'Name',
        'required',
        'id'                            => 'name',
        'data-parsley-required-message' => 'Name is required',

        'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout'
    ]) !!}
```

notice `$user->name`
the problem is i cant retrieve coordinates variables and put there values in the field of the update form so when i use $user->location or $user->CheckInLocation ,as u can see in the object above , it bring me nothing ,
[image show the form update coordinates fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k6oV.png)
this is the tag for coordiantes field in update form :-

```html
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Locations">Locations</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <button id="stop_btn" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-default" onclick="locationClick(); this.disabled = 'disabled';">Location</button>
            <button id="pick_btn" class="btn btn-info" onclick="pickClick(); this.disabled = 'disabled';">Pickup Location</button>
            <button id="drop_btn" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="dropClick(); this.disabled = 'disabled'; {{ $user->CheckOutLocation }}">Dropoff Location</button>
            <div id="map" value="{{ $user->CheckOutLocation }}"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

so can any one help me to figure how can i make old values of coordintes appear in their fields of update form , thanks in advance , i hope every thing is clear.

Comment: is `$user->CheckOutLocation` returning empty , or it is not showing on MAP ?

Comment: it return nothing bro

Comment: ok. so I think you should first check if problem is in view or your controller method . Can you use `dd($user)` in your controller and check if values are present there ? or simply `dd($user->CheckOutLocation )`  . Same for other 2 attribute of location

Comment: all are null bro ?! //and btw thk for helping me :))

Comment: look bro i did't made a database table for location i gust made a model and made a $fillable varabile with array of its attributes ... does change any thing ?

Comment: what is the data type for you location attribute in your DB? also, could you post how you are storing the location in DB,most probably your values are not getting stored in the DB(u can confirm on console) , though it should have thrown an error while storing

Comment: What DB u r using ? MYSQL ?

Comment: Yes mysql ! bro

Comment: ok, so now what you can do is use the 2 fields for each location with floating point Or use the Spatial extension for MySQL and laravel to store the location info..

Comment: spatial extention for MySQL => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: spatial extension  for Laravel => https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial